# urlrewrite in IIS vs replace http with https in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

What is difference in security point of view, implementing https with IIS UrlRewrite and implementing https by replacing http with https in the URL in application start event of global.asax dotnet code.

Comment: Do you want to learn if anyone can somehow turn off your HTTP to HTTPS redirection? Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to know which is more secured. Bcoz before redirection to https, the request is over http which is not encrypted yet. Also when in the http pipeline is the URL getting encrypted in both the cases. With that I will know which is more secured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL rewrite get executed in the begin request event in IIS pipeline. There's no apparent difference in security level when you redirect http to https.

When you enable SSL in IIS manager, http and https side-by-side is not supported because schannel will break it. So you may need to create another site to handle the http binding and implement https redirection. In this case, both of them should be safe.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link.